# implementing quaternions to euler angle conversion in python

Tags: python, math, quaternions, euler-angles

I am trying to write a custom function that takes a quaternion and outputs the Euler angles.
I thought it was quite easy: I am using the formulas found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles#Quaternion_to_Euler_angles_conversion) while also looking at the C++ implementation in the same page.
The function looks like this:

```
import math    
def quaternion_to_euler(quaternion: tuple):
        w, x, y, z = quaternion
        roll = math.atan2(2*(w*x + y*z), 1 - 2*(x * x + y * y))
        pitch = math.asin(2*(w*y - z*x))
        yaw = math.atan2(2*(w*z + x*y), 1 - 2*(y * y + z * z))
        return(roll, pitch, yaw)
```

To be sure of having the good results, I am comparing my conversion with the one performed by [this page](https://www.andre-gaschler.com/rotationconverter/).

It seems that my results are completely off. As an example compare the results of my function for a specific quaternion:

```
quaternion = (0.73007, -0.03484,  0.68173,  0.03199)
roll, pitch, yaw = quaternion_to_euler(quaternion)
print(f'roll: {roll}, pitch: {pitch}, yaw: {yaw}')
roll: -0.10618318122804299, pitch: 1.5022308055111253, yaw: -0.011586976613645479
```

To the results of the page linked above:

```
roll: -0.9466037, pitch: 1.454085, yaw: 0.9425664
```

The formulas seem quite straightforward to me, and I cannot see any self-evident mistake in the implementation. Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong ?

EDIT:

I found out that there is a `scipy` class that support the conversion between quaternion and euler angle. If I do:

```
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation as R
rr = R.from_quat([-0.03484,  0.68173,  0.03199, 0.73007])
print(rr.as_euler('xyz'))
```

I have exactly the same results as my custom function. Now I am even more confused.

Comment: Are you sure the page you linked is using the same math as you?

Comment: @MattDMo, well, no, but still, the results should be the same, shouldn't they ?

Answer (score 0):

For Euler angles, the rotation order matters.

It seems that your reference Euler angles result is XYZ ordered rotation but your result is ZYX ordered rotation.

The page whose link you provided also mentions about it around 'Body 3-2-1 sequence' parts.